# How can I programmatically clear text selection in InDesign with ExtendScript?

Tags: adobe, textselection, extendscript, adobe-indesign

I've programmatically selected some text in InDesign using ExtendScript:

```
app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.findGrepPreferences.appliedFont = myFont;
var matches = app.activeDocument.findGrep();
if(matches.length > 0) {
  matches[0].select();
}
```

How can I deselect it now? Is there no function for this, like `app.clearSelections();` or something of the sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
app.activeDocument.select(NothingEnum.NOTHING);
```