# Select all text in thread in InDesign?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm attempting to select all text in a thread in InDesign CS4 so I can call another script (not made by me) on the selected text using `doScript`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743073/how-can-i-programmatically-clear-text-selection-in-indesign-with-extendscript) makes me think it is possible. I tried `frame.contents.select();`, but this gives the error "frame.contents.select is not a function."

How can I select the *contents* of a thread in InDesign using extendscript / javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Any_text_item).contents` is a plain text *interface* only; it does not directly access InDesign's native [`Text` object](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Text.html), but instead text is translated to and from a regular Javascript string. So selecting the Javascript text (if possible) would do nothing to the text in the InDesign document itself.

To get all threaded text from any text frame (or other object), you can use its `parentStory` object. To select the (native) text, target its `texts[0]` property and use `select` on that:

```
frame.parentStory.texts[0].select();
```

If you can locate at what point the "current selection" is checked, you can add the following lines immediately before it:<sup>1</sup>

```
if (app.selection.length == 1 && app.selection[0].hasOwnProperty("previousTextFrame"))
{
    // alert ('we must be a text frame!');
    app.selection[0].parentStory.texts[0].select();
}
```

For example, in the script `markdownId.jsx` that would be near around line 29, just after

```
tagset = findTagSet();
if (app.selection.length > 0)
{ // <- add the new lines immediately below this one, above the next
     if (app.selection.length == 1 && app.selection[0].hasOwnProperty('baseline') && app.selection[0].length > 1)
```

---

<sup>¹ Best is to test for a property of which you are sure *none* 'unwanted' objects have. Earlier, I used `parentStory` but realized that a plain text selection also has this property, and so it cannot differ between a regular selection and a text frame. For `previousTextFrame` you can be sure that only text frames and text paths are the right kind of object.</sup>

Comment: Haha! It's markdownID I'm trying to script. That's awesome. Trying your solution now...

Comment: Minor update: bad advice (test for `parentStory`) replaced by a better one (test for `previousTextFrame`) ... (You're welcome! Glad to be of help.)

Comment: Any advice on handling character encoding? Your script handles everything perfectly when I let it do the loading; but when I load my own md's, things like quotation marks and apostrophes start getting all weird with gobbly-gook like `‚Äù`.

Comment: @Nathan: that's UTF8 encoding and would indicate that it does not recognize your file as proper UTF8 – see the function `getFromFile`. But I am unable to reproduce this ... I tested with and without the UTF8 BOM marker, and the script works correctly with both.

Comment: Yeah. I don't think it's your script's fault. The odd characters are present after importing before your script does the conversion.

Comment: [I created another question for this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792282/specifying-encoding-while-placing-files-in-indesign-using-extendscript)